# SqlAlchemy ORM query to return a list of Children

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 1 Parent(Parent) tables and 2 Children(Son, Daughter) tables with relationship Many To Many. So i have also 2 secondary tables for each child.

```
class Parent(db.Model):
 id=db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
 name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)

 sons= db.relationship('Son',
                       secondary=parent_has_son,
                       back_populates='parents')

 daughters = db.relationship('Daughter',
                           secondary=parent_has_daughter,
                           back_populates='parents')


Class Son(db.Model):
 id=db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
 name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
 age = db.Column(db.Integer)
 son_other_col = .Column(db.String(45))

 parents =  db.relationship('Parent',
                           secondary=parent_has_son,
                               back_populates='sons')


Class Daughter(db.Model):
     id=db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
     name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
     age = db.Column(db.Integer)
     daughter_other_col1 = .Column(db.String(45))
     daughter_other_col2 = .Column(db.String(45))

     parents =  db.relationship('Parent',
                               secondary=parent_has_daughter,
                               back_populates='daughters')

parent_has_son = db.Table('parent_has_son ', db.metadata,
                                db.Column('parent_id', db.Integer, ForeignKey('Parent.id')),
                                db.Column('son_id', db.Integer, ForeignKey('Son.id')))

parent_has_daughter = db.Table('parent_has_daughter ', db.metadata,
                                    db.Column('parent_id', db.Integer, ForeignKey('Parent.id')),
                                    db.Column('daughter_id', db.Integer, ForeignKey('Daughter.id')))
```

So now I can :

```
db.session.query(Parent).options(joinedload('sons')).options(joinedload('daughters)).filter(Parent.id == 1).first()
```

that will return me a Parent object and i can access children via : Parent.daughters, Parent.sons.

But i want a query to return a list with sons and daughters like:
[Son1, Daughter2, Son2]

if i use this query:

```
db.session.query(Son, Daughter).select_from(Parent).join(Parent.sons).join(Parent.daughters).all()
```

it returns me something like :
[(Son1, Daughter1), (Son2, Daughter1), etc)]

which is not that i want.
I need a query to return me a list with parent's sons and daughters and order them by age. Is that possible??

Answer (score 0):

Create base model `Child` with `children` relationship and use `with_polymorphic`:

```
son_and_daughter = with_polymorphic(Child, [Son, Daughter], flat=True)
```

then use it the following:

```
session.query(Parent).options(
    joinedload(Parent.children.of_type(son_and_daughter))
)
```

See [Inheritance loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance_loading.html)

Comment: i didn't understand the columns Child table must have.

Comment: @nick Base model `Child` must have relationship `parents =  db.relationship('Parent', secondary=parent_has_child, back_populates='children')`

Comment: I can't have a table with only one relationship.I need to have a primary key column and  columns with foreign keys too.